# Replacing URLS with Hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, regex

I found the following function:

```
function addHyperlinks(str) {
    // Set the regex string
    var regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig
    // Replace plain text links by hyperlinks
    var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
    // Echo link
    return replaced_text;
}
```

Which works okay, however when there is a dash in the URL it stops processing there.   So for instance, the following URL:

`http://website.com/some-internet-page`

Will get replaced with:

`<a href='http://website.com/some'>http://website.com/some</a>-internet-page`

I'm not good with regex, could anyone help modify the above so that this doesnt happen?

Comment: Try this one /(https?:\/\/([-\w\-\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\-\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig

Comment: @Tonny yay thank you! if you'd like to put it as an answer I'l mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tonny said it in the comments above:

/(https?://([-\w-.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w-/_.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig

Thank you!